# Uneven numbers of tokens and subscript out of bound errors

Tags: r, linux

I am trying to analyze data from flow cytometry, where there is a package that was developed like 10 years ago. It requires a few dependencies packages that I was able to install all.

Now when I tried to run it with the first function to create a gate frame for a winlist processed fcs file.

```
create_gate_frame(frame = archframe1x36x16, inputfile =c("facsdata/TrungTran/Gelfree-8-lane7-5_1_1_A5.fcs"), popdesc = "frames/popdescriptions/array1xpopdesc.txt").
```

I just got the following errors that I don't know how to solve. So, any help would be very much appreciated.

> - uneven number of tokens: 1013
> - The last keyword is dropped.
> - uneven number of tokens: 1013
> - The last keyword is dropped.
> - Error in mat[, c(scatters, dims1, dims2, PE)] : subscript out of bounds